# Why custome deleters for smart pointers are not allowed to throw exceptions?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, custom-deleter

I'm reading about smart pointers from a book and there it is specified that custom deleter is not allowed to throw. But I could not figure out the reason for this. Why they are not allowed to throw?

Comment: Smart pointer will call a custom deleter in its destructor. Now you have to ask yourself, what an uncaught exception in a destructor would lead to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The deleter held by a smart pointer is expected to run when the smart pointer is destructed, which might be during the stack unwinding between a `throw` and a `catch`.

If your deleter throws in that circumstance, and it isn't caught by the smart pointer's destructor, then to avoid two exceptions being in-flight at the same time, there is a language rule to `std::terminate` the process.

The specific case of `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` do have a precondition that the deleter must never throw when they call it, under pain of undefined behaviour, but they don't require it to be marked `noexcept`.

Comment: Actually, `std::shared_ptr` requires deleter to be non-throwing: http://www.eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared#const-10. `std::unique_ptr` does not seem to have such requirement, probably because every place where it could be called is `noexcept` already.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thanks. Both end up with UB if the deleter throws, `shared_ptr` because that's what you get for violating a precondition, and `unique_ptr` just directly calls it out

Comment: @Yksisarvinen  `noexcept` just short circuits to`try{/*...*/} catch(...){/*noop*/};`. It doesn't provide any guarantees. So the double throw UB is still the problem.

Comment: @Red.Wave no, `noexcept` is like `try{ ... } catch { std::terminate(); }`

Comment: @Caleth yes, my bad. I was more concerned about stack unwinding. Forgot that one.